# How to combine these queries that group by the same field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cached_type_a, DATE(datetime) as datetime
    FROM requests
    WHERE cached = 'a'
    GROUP BY DAY(datetime);

SELECT COUNT(*) as cached_type_b, DATE(datetime) as datetime
    FROM requests
    WHERE cached = 'b'
    GROUP BY DAY(datetime);

SELECT COUNT(*) as cached_type_c, DATE(datetime) as datetime
    FROM requests
    WHERE cached = 'c'
    GROUP BY DAY(datetime);
```

Is it possible to combine them into a single query with 4 columns

`cached_type_a`, `cached_type_b`, `cached_type_c`, `datetime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only three possible values of `cache`, you can use this,

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) as datetime,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cached_a,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cached_b,
        SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cached_c
FROM requests
GROUP BY DAY(datetime)
```

otherwise, if you have multiple number of cache, you can use `Prepared Statement`

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN cached =  ''',
      cached,
      ''' then 1 ELSE 0 end) AS ',
      CONCAT('cached_',cached)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM requests;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE(datetime) as datetime, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM requests 
                   GROUP BY DAY(datetime)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way I can divide each of those `SUM` statements by `SUM(1)` and then multiply by `100`?

Comment: It's the total of all records in a day, ex `SELECT DATE(datetime) as datetime, SUM(1) total, SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cached_a, ...`

Comment: try this if it works, sorry, can't test because i have no data, `SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT COUNT(a.datetime) as cached_type_a,
        COUNT(b.datetime) as cached_type_b,
        COUNT(c.datetime) as cached_type_c,
        DATE(a.datetime) as datetime
 FROM requests a, 
      requests b,
      requests c,  
 WHERE a.cached = 'a' 
   and b.cached = 'b'
   and c.cached = 'c'
 GROUP BY DAY(a.datetime), DAY(b.datetime), DAY(c.datetime);
```